# Can Ngxs @Select decorator return a BehaviorSubject instead of an Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

Currently, I have a few `@Select` tags in my code for which I would like to save the state locally in the component. They look like this:

```js
@Select(myState.editing)
editing$: Observable<boolean>;
editing: boolean;

this.editing$.subscribe((e: boolean) => {
  this.editing = e;
});
```

It seems like there should be a way to have `@Select` return a `BehaviorSubject`, so that I could do something like:

```js
@Select(myState.editing)
editing$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>
```

And then I could just access the `editing$.value` to check that piece of state.
When I tried this, it compiled, but `editing$` just acted like a regular `Observable` rather than a `BehaviorSubject` (it didn't have a `value` property). I feel like I'm just not understanding the correct usage of Ngxs, since the pattern I'm using seems pretty verbose. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you wanting to access the value in the template (html) or component file, or both?

Comment: Both, ideally. I know that in the template I can do (editing$ | async). I would like to be able to do something like that in the component.ts file.

Comment: You might think about creating a child component that just takes in the editing value from the async pipe. Not saying you're doing anything wrong by accessing the value in the observable, I just know that it adds complexity that can be avoided. Use a parent component to select the state and a child component that uses the state values. What Garth Mason is saying is also valuable too, but I would use the https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy operators for easier unsubscribing.

Answer (score 0):

The first option you described, subscribing to that selector in your component and capturing it in a variable `editing` is fine (don't forget to unsubscribe on when the component is destroyed).

Another option is if you just want to grab it on demand when you need it (rather than keeping it in a variable you update) then you can use the `selectSnapshot` function defined on the store e.g `this.store.selectSnapshot(myState.editing)`, which gives you the current value in the state, but does not subscribe to it.